# Convert multiple percentages to fit into 100%

Tags: c#, math, percentage

I basically have a script that populates an area in a game, You can add multiple objects to populate the area and they all have a spawn Chance value from 0.00 - 1.00 attached.

I'm trying to convert those spawn chances to fit into 100%, so that 3 objects with with 1.00 will convert to 0.33% or 3 objects with 50% will also convert to 0.33%. Or lastly, 3 objects with: 0.4, 0.4, 0.2 - Will convert to: 40, 40, 20 (I hope thats right).

I'm trying, probably in the wrong direction, this at the moment:

```
void GetRanges()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < clutterObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        temp += clutterObjects[i].spawnChance;
    }

    if (temp > 1.0)
    {
        temp = temp - 1.0f;

        for (int i = 0; i < clutterObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            clutterObjects[i].spawnChance -= 
                clutterObjects[i].spawnChance * temp;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        temp = Mathf.Abs(temp - 1.0f);
        for (int i = 0; i < clutterObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            clutterObjects[i].spawnChance += 
                clutterObjects[i].spawnChance * temp;
        }
    }

    Spawn();
}
```

Anyone know how to go about this, Or what a better solution may be.

Comment: Why should 3 objects with 100% convert to the same thing as 3 objects with 50%?

Comment: Because they should convert so that all added together equal 100% (i'm probably thinking about this wrong)

Comment: Okay, so the "Chance Value" is a weight?  An object with a 0.5 should spawn twice as frequently as an object with a 0.25?  But no matter what the sum of the weights, the sum of the percentages should always be 100%.

Comment: The correct values for 0.5, 0.5 and 0.25 would be 40, 40 and 20 btw.

Comment: Shows how good i am with this, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to divide by the overall sum -- that will normalize the values to a total of 1.  Start with the sum of all 3, and then divide each one by the sum to get the normalized probability.

```
double[] probabilities = { 1, 1, 1 }
double sum = probabilities.Sum();
double[] normalized = probabilities.Select(prob => prob/sum).ToArray();
```

Or, working with your example:

```
void GetRanges()
{
    double sum = clutteredObjects.Sum(obj => obj.spawnChance);

    for (int i = 0; i < clutterObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        clutterObjects[i].spawnChance /= sum;
    }

    Spawn();
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, always try and go in the wrong direction with these things.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a weighted average of your parts that totals to 100.

Add them all together to get the total amount, then multiply them all by 100 and divide by your total.

```
float temp = 0f;
for (int i = 0; i < clutterObjects.Length; i++)
    temp += clutterObject[i].spawnChance;
for (int i = 0; i < clutterObjects.Length; i++)
    clutterObjects[i].spawnChance *= 100f / temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow this approach:

1. Sum the weights (chances)
2. Divide 1 by the sum
3. Multiply each weight by the value obtained in 2

That will give you *normalized* weights, where the sum of the normalized weights will be 1.

Here is a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    double[] weights = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.25 };
    double sum = weights.Sum();
    double factor = 1.0 / sum;
    double[] normalizedWeights = weights.Select(w => w * factor).ToArray();
    double[] percentages = normalizedWeights.Select(w => 100.0 * w).ToArray();
    percentages.Dump();
    percentages.Sum().Dump();
}
```

Output:

```
40
40
20

100
```